# Handling an event on click of a button

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, dialog, itext

I am making a button in C# 4.0. I want to click this button and I want to open a dialog box inside the adobe reader. So I am making use of itextsharp also. Please let me know what must I use to make this dialog box work?

```
PushbuttonField button1 = new PushbuttonField(
    stamper.Writer,
    new Rectangle(90, 660, 140, 690), "Add Context");
button1.Text = "Add Context";
```

Comment: maybe are you looking for the `click` event? I'm not sure about your question...

Comment: i want to click this button and then a dialog must open

Comment: You talked about adobe reader also. Can you explain what adobe is doing here?

Comment: Open a dialog box in adobe reader? Clearly specify your need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have inherited from [the base `Button` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx), you can do:

```
this.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
//there you have an event:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //open the dialog box here...
}
```

Comment: well i dont inherit from button base class as specied i am on C# 4.0

Comment: at least, you should inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Control`

Comment: i tried with this as well i wrote using system.windows and it appereda a red line over it

Answer (score 0):

```
button1.Text = "Add Context";
button1.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);

protected void button_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
//  perform necessary actions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers don't match the question.

The question is about a button in a PDF file. When somebody clicks on this button a dialog box needs to open.

The answers are about buttons in a C# application. There's a huge difference between a button in such an application and a button in Adobe Reader.

The question can't be answered in its current phrasing because it's not clear what you want to do with the dialog box in Adobe Reader. If you want a simple alert message, that's easy to achieve. If you expect you can create a dialog box with the same level of functionality available in a C# application, please forget the idea: you may be asking something that is completely impossible.

Comment: i want to take in some values form this dialog box; on the other hand i have got signature fields that i wish to attach with the button in a way as when user opens up the dialog box he must be given an option for a drop down meny in which user can select appropriate signature fiedl

Comment: You need JavaScript to do this. Please download one of the JavaScript reference manuals here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html It's not clear what you mean by 'signature fields I wish to attach with the button' and 'user can select appropriate signature field'. Seems like you want to do something that is impossible (but then again: I don't know what you want to do). Did you read http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures ?

Comment: i made a C# (windows based) i needd a button on this on the click of this button i selected another windows form (dialog)/form2 i have designed this windows form so far i also put an adobe reader pdf conatiner just to hold pdf files ; now i want to load a pdf file that has sign fields on it i want to selct appropriate field using the form 2 on which the desing is done ; i want to put in some data related to that field convert it to xml ; when i again open the same pdf with adobe reader i want to put that input data on that sign field this is what i am doing

Comment: In that case, I would advise you NOT to put the buttons in the PDF document. Your requirement to establish a communication between the JavaScript in a PDF document, a C# application and a second PDF document can't be met. The fact that your question is unanswerable explains why you don't get any useful answer.